# How to calculate a relative path from two absolute paths in Linux shell?

Tags: linux, command-line, shell, path

We have two paths. First one is directory, second either a directory or a file.

`/a/b/c` and `/a/d/e.txt`

Relative path from first path to second will be:

`../../d/e.txt`

How to calculate that in Linux terminal? For those who ask “What is usage case?” one could use this—for example—to create lots of relative symlinks.

Comment: This should not have been migrated.

Comment: It should have been closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 11):

Assuming GNU coreutils:

- For symlinks, `ln` has recently learned the `--relative` option.
- For everything else, `realpath` supports options `--relative-to=` and `--relative-base=`.

Comment: How do you do it with BusyBox?

Answer (score 5):

For me, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7305217/2880699) answer (which uses a python oneliner) works perfect.

```
$ python -c "import os.path; print os.path.relpath('/a/d/e.txt', '/a/b/c')"
../../d/e.txt
```

Tested successfully on linux (Kubuntu 14.04) an on Mac OSX, needs Python 2.6.

Answer (score 3):

To not depend on `realpath` that is not consistently available and minimize the dependencies, I came up with this (using a little help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6973268/275195)):

```bash
function relative_path_from_to() {
  # strip trailing slashes
  path1=${1%\/}
  path2=${2%\/}
  # common part of both paths
  common=$(printf '%s\x0%s' "${path1}" "${path2}" | sed 's/\(.*\/\).*\x0\1.*/\1/')
  # how many directories we have to go up to the common part
  up=$(grep -o "/" <<< ${path1#$common} | wc -l)
  # create a prefix in the form of ../../ ...
  prefix=""; for ((i=0; i<=$up; i++)); do prefix="$prefix../"; done
  # return prefix plus second path without common
  printf "$prefix${2#$common}"
}
```

Spawns a subshell for finding the common part of both pathes. I hope you like it - works for me.

Comment: Be careful common this doesn't work for `relative_path_from_to /path/test1/file /path/test2/file` gives `../../2/file` instead of `../../test2/file`. To fix that the sed part must be updated to `s/\(.*\/\).*\x0\1.*/\1/` (force end with a slash)

Comment: Hi @mems - you are totally right. Thank you for the fix. This is what you get if you don't write test cases...